# LINQ Query And Operator Perfomance

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb

I have a LINQ Query which searches MongoDB for more than 50 million records. I am using the and operator in my query like below:

```
(from e in this.collection.AsQueryable<SocialRecord>()
where
    bArray.Contains(e.TermMonitorIds) &&
    (sources.Contains(e.SocialType)) &&
    (e.DateCreated >= fr) &&
    (e.DateCreated <= to)
select e)
.OrderByDescending(e => e.SocialCount)
.ToList();
```

Does it make any performance improvement if I change the query the way below:

```
(from e in this.collection.AsQueryable<SocialRecord>()
where
    (e.DateCreated >= fr) &&
    (e.DateCreated <= to) && 
    bArray.Contains(e.TermMonitorIds) &&
    (sources.Contains(e.SocialType)) 
select e)
.OrderByDescending(e => e.SocialCount)
.ToList();
```

..because `DateCreated` is the one which separates the huge quantity of records. Is there a way to improve the above query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this was an in-memory lookup then yes it would be quicker because C# uses short-circuit evaluation for the [`&&` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/2a723cdk.aspx) therefore checking the date range first would filter out nodes which don't match.

However, I am not sure of the inner workings of mongoDB so it would really depend on whether it also supported short-circuit evaluation for the `AND` conditions.

---

Turns out MongoDB *does* support [short-circuit evaluation for $and](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/).

Comment: Just wondering how you short circuit evaluate an "and" condition? An "or" condition I get since something evaluates before testing the others. Love to here the explanation of how that applies to an "and". And certainly yes, what this is actually about is how the LINQ serializes as a request. Which would probably be required in an answer.

Comment: @NeilLunn see the docs on how the [&& operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/2a723cdk.aspx) works. Specifically "*The conditional-AND operator (&&) performs a logical-AND of its bool operands, **but only evaluates its second operand if necessary**.*".

Comment: I think I get that. But look at the conditions specified and ask yourself "Is it necessary?" I would generally think that a list of differing conditions require the evaluation to be necessary. It wouldn't be the first piece of creative licence I have ever read in documentation, and if you read that statement again it is very open to interpretation. But that does not make the impossible so.

Comment: @NeilLunn not sure how it's open to interpretation, the docs are pretty clear. If I have a condition like `a && b && c && d` the behaviour dictates that `b` is only evaluated if `a` is `true` and then `c` is only evaluated if `b` is true and so on. "*is it necessary?*" - clearly in the OP's case it is because the lookups on `bArray` / `sources` could be expensive and it would make sense to only perform those lookups on items which match the date filter.